# Which LESS files do you compile in a child theme?

Tags: magento2, theme, less, less-compilation

I'm trying to create a theme based on [Pixtron](https://www.hiddentechies.com/pixtron-responsive-theme-prestashop.html). I'm using Gulp rather than Grunt, but everything I've read about compiling LESS files has the same instructions: you have point to the source file(s) (e.g. styles-m.less or styles-l.less) in `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/web/css` and point the destination files in `pub/static/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/<locale>/css`.

Pixtron uses Magento/blank as its parent theme. So, I think because of that, there are no overarching theme files directly in the css folder. There are files inside the source subfolder to extend/override the blank theme. Here's the folder structure:

```
<Theme_Dir>
|  |-- web/
|  |  |-- css/
|  |  |  |-- source/
|  |  |  |  |-- _custom.less
|  |  |  |  |-- _extends.less
|  |  |  |  |-- _navigation.less
|  |  |  |  |-- _theme.less
```

So, I guess my question is which files should I be compiling when there aren't any main theme files for me to use? Should I be using the styles-l/m files from the parent theme? Hopefully, my question makes sense.